# How to inherit the property from a parent class in the child class?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

This may be a repeated question, however i don't find suitable solution for my case

i have below two class

class Account

```
class Account():
    
    
    def __init__(self, acnt_type, id, name):
        self.account_type = acnt_type
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
      
        
        
    
    def create_account(self) -> dict:
        account_details ={}
        account_details['acnt_type']= self.account_type
        account_details['id']= self.id
        account_details['name']=self.name
        return account_details
    
     @property  
     def acount_type(self):
         return self.account_type
    
     @acount_type.setter  
     def account_type(self, new_acount_value):
         self.account_type = new_acount_value
```

class Customer

```
class Customer(Account):
    
    def __init__(self,acount_type, id, name):
        super().__init__(acount_type, id, name)
    
    @Account.account_type.getter
    def acount_type(self):
        return super(Customer, Customer).account_type.__get__(self)
    
    @Account.account_type.setter
    def account_type(self, new_acount_value):
        super(Customer, Customer).account_type.__set__(self,new_acount_value)
```

Invoking the class

```
acnt_type, id, name = ('savings', '101','Umesh')
obj = Customer(acount_type=acnt_type, id= id, name=name)

details = obj.create_account()

print(details)

obj.account_type='Fixed'

print(details)
```

But getting below error

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

#Expected:

```
Initial run
details = obj.create_account()

print(details)
{'acnt_type': 'savings', 'id': '101', 'name': 'Umesh'}

-- Updating account type
obj.account_type='Fixed'

print(details)

{'acnt_type': 'Fixed', 'id': '101', 'name': 'Umesh'}
```

Any solution to this? is the right approach while inheriting property from the parent class in python?

Comment: The property is _already_ inherited, why are you trying to override it with the exact same implementation again? Right now your subclass doesn't need _any_ implementation, it can inherit everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct property name
2. Don't use setter in constructor. Create private field and use it.
3. No additional steps needed for inheritance. Propery is inherited automatically.

```py
class Account():

    def __init__(self, acnt_type, id, name):
        self.__account_type = acnt_type
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def create_account(self) -> dict:
        account_details = {}
        account_details['acnt_type'] = self.account_type
        account_details['id'] = self.id
        account_details['name'] = self.name
        return account_details

    @property
    def account_type(self):
        return self.__account_type

    @account_type.setter
    def account_type(self, new_acount_value):
        self.__account_type = new_acount_value


class Customer(Account):
    def __init__(self, acount_type, id, name):
        super().__init__(acount_type, id, name)
```

```py
acnt_type, id, name = ('savings', '101', 'Umesh')
obj = Customer(acount_type=acnt_type, id=id, name=name)

print(obj.create_account())
# {'acnt_type': 'savings', 'id': '101', 'name': 'Umesh'}

obj.account_type = 'Fixed'
print(obj.create_account())
# {'acnt_type': 'Fixed', 'id': '101', 'name': 'Umesh'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is not with the inheritance itself, but the fact you are using the same name of the property as the attribute storage in the base class itself.

When you do:

```
     @property  
     def acount_type(self):
         return self.account_type
```

This will alone get you a recursion error - as `self.account_type` is the code that triggers the `account_type` getter to be called.

If you put a single underscore ("_") when making the attribute access inside the property, you avoid that name clash, and things will just work:

```
     @property  
     def acount_type(self):
         return self._account_type
```

(and the same in the setter).

As for inheriting: this working property will work as it is on any subclass, and the way you are making to recreate the property is correct ( using `@Account.account_type.getter` to decorate an override to the getter of the base class property . However, after you do it for the *getter* you should not use the same strategy to create the "setter", as it will create a new setter based on the property of the base class, not on the property for which you just created a setter in the child class. In other words:

```
class Parent:
   @property
   def prop(self):
      # base getter
      ...
   @prop.setter(self, v):
      #  base setter


class Child(Parent):
    @Parent.prop.getter
    def prop(self):
        # fine, this creates a new property, with a new getter on the child
        ...
        parent_value = super().prop  
        # code transforming parent_value if needed
        ...
        return parent_value
  
    @Parent.prop.setter   # Incorrect
    def prop(self, value):
        #This will duplicate the property in Parent, and create a new, child, setter. But the child getter above will be forgotten
```

Instead, after overriding the getter on the child class, decorate the setter simply like:

```
class Child(Parent):
    @Parent.prop.getter
    def prop(self):
        # fine, this creates a new property, with a new getter on the child
        ...
    @prop.setter   
    def prop(self, value):
        #This will add a new setter to the property created with the new getter above
        ...
        # transform value if needed
        super(Child, Child).prop.__set__(self, value)
```

And finally, as you  can see in the snippets above, the way to use `super()` to have access to the properties as they are defined in the superclasse. For reading the property purposes, the parameterless form of super() will work - but for setting or deleting the attribute, you have to retrieve the property object itself, and explicitly call its `__set__`  or `__delete__` methods:

```
class Child:
    ...
    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, value):
        ...
        super(Customer, Customer).account_type.__set__(self, value)
```